# Django Upload From Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am looking into uploading a file from the html template. I've seen a fair amount of documentation including FileFields, ImageFields etc. However, ideally I do not want to rewrite my code. 
Currently, I have a simple form on my template and I would like to have an upload function there, where, an image will be uploaded and stored into my applications media folder and if possible added to a database.

I do know that I've probably taken a long and complex route but if anyone can help it'll be great!

html.py:

> ```
> <div class="row">                 <div class="span1 offset5">                 </bR>
>               <form class="form-horizontal" method="get" action="/add/submit" value="add">  
>               <fieldset>              <div class="input">
>               <div class="inline-inputs">
>               <label>Ride Name:</label><input type="text" name="name">
>               <label>Type:</label><input type="text" name="type">
>               <label>Theme:</label><input type="text" name="theme">
>               <label>Description:</label><textarea rows="5" name ="description"></textarea>
>               <label>Author:</label><input type="text" name="author">
>
>               <label>Date Released:</label>
>               <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
>                   <input type="text" name="date"></input>
>                   <span class="add-on">
>                   <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
>                   </span>
>               </div>                      
>               <label>Thread:</label><input type="text" name="thread">
>               <label>Video</label><textarea rows="2" name ="video"></textarea>
>
>
>                   <br><br>
>                   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add" />
>                   </div>              </div>                      
>
>                </fieldset> 
>               </form>  
>               </div>  </div>
> ```

Currently my Views.py just takes the entered data and inserts it into a database. I want to add the ability for a file to be uploaded:

```
def Ride_Add_Submit(request):
    name = request.GET['name']
    type = request.GET['type']
    theme = request.GET['theme']
    description = request.GET['description']
    author = request.GET['author']
    releasedate=request.GET['date']
    video=request.GET['video']
    thread=request.GET['thread']


    entry = RollerCoaster(name=name, type=type, theme=theme, description=description, releasedate=releasedate, author=author, video=video, thread=thread)
    entry.save()
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'Ride_Add.html')
```

Comment: I think you should rewrite your code. For you can't upload file via GET request. Then I would recommend you to use ImageField, for it makes all the behavior you described.

Comment: If your form is designed only to create objects in databse I would recommend you to use ModelForm  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. 
I was completely unaware of modelforms. I have read a few books and followed numerous tutorials and this is the first time I've come across them.
thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you keep talking about the template here, the template has nothing whatsoever to do with anything. The handling of the upload, like all logic, is done in the view.

The [file upload overview](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files) still has all the information you need. You can ignore the parts about the Django form and checking if it's valid, and simply pass the file object to your upload handling function, which that page also explains.

However you will need to change your template so that the form element uses POST instead of GET (which is almost certainly a good idea anyway), and use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as also described on that page.

Finally, I really would advise you to rewrite your code to use ModelForms. Not only would it make your code much simpler, it would also do things like validate the entry to make sure all the required fields are present and are of the right types, and so on - as well as output valid HTML (for instance, you're missing `for` attributes in your `label` tags).

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented my code to use ModelForms now. Thank you